# Logisim red wire bug

Tags: logisim

When I add a wire segment to a wire that's turned on, it turns red (even though I'm not connecting it to anything else). In fact, any wire passing over that particular dot in the schematic turns red. Is this a bug? What can I do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce this issue. What version of Logisim are you using?

Comment: I've seen this problem. My workaround was to restart Logisim.

Comment: Logisim's menu has a command "Reset simulation" that helps in most of such situations.